# PGSQL could not fork new process for connection

Tags: postgresql

when I try to connect my postgresql database I get an error message "could not fork new process for connection : No error could not fork new process for connection"

Comment: This is not going to get an answer without more information: 1) Postgres version(which should always be provided) 2) The client used to make connection and it's version. 3) The actual connection code with connection parameters. 4) Relevant information from Postgres log. **Add information as update to question**.

Answer (score 1):

You either have exceeded the `ulimit` of processes for the PostgreSQL user, or you have run out of memory. There are perhaps other causes, but these are the most frequent. You will have to determine the cause and fix the operating system and/or PostgreSQL configuration.

Reduce your `max_connections` to a reasonable limit like 100 and make sure that `work_mem` is not excessively high.

Comment: re: "work_mem is not excessively high." `work_mem` is the upper bound of MEM that a forked process may use? In other words, if work_mem is 100 MB, but the queries are `SELECT 1`, surely 100 MB won't be used on each fork?

Comment: @KevinMeredith `work_mem` is not a limit per process, but per execution plan step. But yes, it is an upper limit. For queries like `SELECT 1`, very little memory will be allocated.